# How to access washer in old tap/faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I have a leaky tap, I've tried to follow some guides for how to fix this, but they all seem to be for much newer taps than I have.

I've taken out a screw and thought I would be able to lift the top off and have access to the internals.  But it does not want to come off.  I can't see anything on the tap to indicate the make/model of it.  If anyone has seen this sort of tap before and could offer some pointers it would be much appreciated

The tap:
[image: My tap]

Comment: That set screw was there to secure the tap handle. Try spraying a little WD40 up under the handle, let it sit, and then gently tap up from below the handle around the edges. It's probably corroded. Once you get the handle off that collar will probably need to be removed. If there is no set screw try rotating it counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to get the actual tap handle off to do this.

There may be a screw under the 'button' top, the white bit with hot/cold which you can get to by prising the 'button' out [I've no clue what they're actually called], though the side screw whilst less common would appear to be the right place. It might just be crusty with age.

However, your access to the washer will be below the bell-shaped top. This should unscrew - though they can be tough to move if they've been in situ a long time. You could prep it by soaking with descaler if you're in a hard water area [though I don't see any evidence of scale in your pic] & a day soaking in WD-40 sprayed onto the thread at the bottom & also dribbled down the hole at the top. Patience can be a virtue ;)

You will then need a 'jam jar opener' style rubber strap pipe wrench to get the cover off.

[image]

Under that will be a hex nut & below that your washer.
If you're lucky you can get to both without removing the tap handle at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Just went to give it a try and the bell top unscrewed easily